# Got lost with branches, origin, upstream repos and two machines in Git and Github. Need guidance

Tags: git, github

First time posting a question here, I hope I've got this right.

I just got stuck on a somehow complex git situation here involving multiple machines, one forked repo with branches and etc.

I've two computers, one forked repo with two branches (master and feat) on my github account configured as 'origin' and the 'upstream' as the original repo that belongs to my organization.

I want to pull everything from the forked repo in the right way into the second machine.

What I've done:

1. cloned the forked repo
2. added upstream (organization repo) as a remote repo
3. pull everything from origin master into local master
4. create a local feat branch with the exact same name
5. pull everything from the feat branch on origin to my local feat branch

Here's the situation on machine #2:

```
  6     2 34 5
O-O-O-O-O-0-0
  \/
   O
   1
```

On the first machine, I've no idea what's going on:

```
      3 4 
O-O-O-O-O-0-0
  \
   O
  5,7
```

Whereas:

1. origin/feat
2. origin/master
3. upstream/master
4. local/master
5. local/feat
6. origin/feat
7. upstream/feat

The commits represented by zero instead of the letter 'o' indicates merge commits. The first one is "Merge pull request #17 from mguidoti/master" the second is " Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/comments-and-docstrings' into comments-and-docstrings", which is the actual name of the feat branch.

My question here is.. have I got this right? I want to have the feat branch on origin and local machines sync with the master branch, which should be updated across all repos and machines.

I could use any help or clarification.

Thanks a lot, and, sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would ever fork your own repo on github. But having done so, it seems to me that you should follow the standard fork protocols: you clone the fork, not the original, you use the fork as your remote, and you use github to communicate between the fork and the original: to update yourself from the original, update from the original to the fork and from the fork to you, and to influence what's in the original, push to the fork and make a pull request to the original. You should not use the original as a second remote. You just confuse yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to think about the issues:

- Hash IDs are unique per commit: every commit gets its own, and either that commit exists in that repository under that hash ID, or the commit just isn't there at all in that repository.  *Every* Git agrees that *that* commit gets *that* hash ID, whether or not the Git in question has that commit.  They've all arranged this in advance somehow (through cryptographic hashing trickiness).
- Gits *find* commits by names: branch names, which are local to this particular Git repository, or any other names.  Each repository maintains its own set of names.  Any name holds only *one* hash ID.
- Gits *share* commits, between different clones of the same original Git repository, by commit hash IDs.
- When Gits are sharing, one Git sends commits and the other receives.  That is, you pick one Git repository and run `git fetch remote` or `git push remote branch`.  That has this one Git repository call up the other Git repository at the URL stored in the *`remote`* name.

A remote name is a simple string, like `origin` or `upstream`.  Each Git has its own remote names.

The transferring mechanisms for fetch and push are very similar, with a big difference at the end of the process—and of course the directions are different.  With `git fetch`, you connect "your" Git to "their" Git and *get* (receive) commits.  With `git push`, you connect yours to theirs but then *send* commits.  Let's concentrate on the `fetch` side, as it's overall more interesting here.

Remember, too, that each commit itself stores the raw hash ID of its immediately previous (or *parent*) commit.  This is what links commits together.  When we draw a branch like this:

```
A--B--C   <--master
```

what we really have is that the *branch name* `master` holds the raw hash ID of the commit we're calling `C` here for convenience.  Then `C` itself holds the hash ID of commit `B`, which holds the hash ID of commit `A`.  So we can always find all commits by starting at the *last* ones—the IDs stored in branch names, for instance—and working backwards.  Git always has to work backwards.

So: when you run `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up another Git, using the URL stored under the name `origin`.  *Their* Git lists out all their branch names and hash IDs.  Since hash IDs are *shared* across all Git repositories, your Git can quickly check each one and see whether you have that commit.  If you do, your Git says *I have hash ID H*, but if not, your Git says *I want hash ID H*.

If you want a commit, their Git offers you its parent(s).  Your Git checks: *Do I have these IDs?*  If not, your Git wants them.  If you already have them, your Git says *No thanks, I have that one.*  At the end of this process, your Git and their Git have a list of all the commits they'll send you, *and* they know about commits you already have (and therefore file versions you already have).  So they send you the commits you need, and you already have the rest, and now you have any commits they had in their branches that you didn't, plus everything you already had.

In other words, if you had:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

you might now have:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D--E
```

where `E` is the commit that *their* `master` identified, `E`'s parent is `D`, and `D`'s parent is `C`.  But Git can only find commits *backwards*, from the ends.  You need some *name* by which to find commit `E`.

Well, *their* name, `master`, is almost good enough.  But it automatically conflicts with your name `master`.  So your Git *renames* their branch names.  Your Git turns their `master` into your `origin/master`.  The `origin/` part comes from the fact that you called up their Git under the name `origin`.  These `origin/master` style names are *remote-tracking names*.  (Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, but I think it's better to toss the word *branch* out of this phrase—it's just cluttering it up and weakening the already-overly-loaded word *branch*.)

After this particular `git fetch`, then, your Git will create or update your `origin/master` to point to newly acquired commit `E`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D--E   <-- origin/master
```

If you run `git fetch upstream` and call up some Git named `upstream`, they'll have some commits.  Maybe they have commit `D`, for instance, as *their* `master`.  But you do have `D` now, so you tell them: *No thanks, already have `D`.*  If that's the end of the list, your Git now creates your `upstream/master` to match `upstream`'s `master`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- upstream/master
         \
          E   <-- origin/master
```

Note that *each Git gets its own set of names*.  They have their branch names, you have your branch names, and your Git renames their branch names to your remote-tracking names.  Your remote-tracking names are built by sticking your *remote* name, `origin` or `upstream`, in front of *their branch* names (plus the slash to keep them from running together).

If you want them—whoever they are, wherever these repositories reside—to change *their* branch names, well, you can do that.  *How* you do that varies.  The simplest method is `git push`, but `git push` requires that you have permission to write on these repositories.

If you *don't* have permission to write on their repositories, you'll need them—whoever they are—to either give you permission, or to do the update themselves.  This is where *forking* comes in, with GitHub and other providers.  A fork is essentially a clone, but with some extra linkage that the provider saves.  If you have a repository that you cannot write on, you can fork it to your own copy.  You can write on this copy.  So now you have a repository on GitHub (or other provider) to which you *can* write.

You can `git fetch` from the original repository—most people call this one `upstream`—but you cannot `git push` to it.  You can `git fetch` from your fork-clone, which you'll probably call `upstream`, and you *can* `git push` to this copy.  And, last, you have *your own* Git repository, on your computer (not on GitHub).  This last one has *your* branches, and all those remote-tracking names.

Now we can get back to `git push`.  This command is as close as Git has to the opposite of `fetch` (and vice versa).  You run, e.g.:

```
git push origin master
```

and your Git calls up the Git at origin—your fork on GitHub, for instance—and offers to GitHub any commits they will need, but don't have, the same way that fetch offers to you any commits you need but don't have.  But once you have given them those commits, the rest is different.

Their Git—your GitHub repository, the one on GitHub that GitHub are managing for you, that you are calling `origin`—has its own branch names.  (Those names were originally copied from the repository you forked.<sup>1</sup>)  So maybe they have:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
```

and you, in your repository, have rearranged yours to read this way:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- origin/master
             \
              F   <-- master
```

So you'll send them commit `F`, which is the one you have that they need, but then ask them to set *their* `master` to point directly to `F`.  They don't set a remote-tracking name!  They set one of their *branch* names.

Now, *they* in this case is sort of you.  This repository is *on* GitHub, but GitHub are managing it for *you*.  Still, that's how you have to do this step: you send commit `F` from your Git on your laptop, say.  Then you ask GitHub's Git-for-you repository to set *its* `master` to point to this new commit `F`.  Since you're allowed to do this, and it meets all the other requirements for a push, they do it.  Now *they* have the `A-B-C-D-E-F` chain and *they* have *their* `master` pointing to `F`.

*Your* Git, on your laptop, sees that they—`origin`—accepted the request to update their `master`.  So your Git updates your `origin/master` now, and now you have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F   <-- master, origin/master
```

If you have an `upstream/master` label in *your* Git repository, nothing happens to it here.  You can run `git fetch upstream` at *any time* though, and have your Git call up their Git—the one on GitHub that isn't yours—and see if they have moved their branch names and/or have any new commits that you don't.

If they *do* have new commits, you can pick them up.  You can do whatever you want with them at this point, including sending them to `origin`.  But, of course, to do that, you'll have to set `origin`'s branch names to point to these commits.  You do will do that with `git push origin`.  **This is where it gets a little tricky.**  (That is, all of the previous stuff was easy!  At least, by comparison.)

---

<sup>1</sup>GitHub's cloning process is a little different from your own: when you clone a repository, your Git renames their branch names to your remote-tracking names, and then creates only *one* branch name in your clone.  When you use GitHub's "fork a repository" button, they clone the other repository, but make exactly the same number of branch names in this clone as were in the repository you just forked.  Those names all holds the same hash IDs, at the moment, as the forked repository.  But since this is a clone, those names are now private to *this* fork: any changes someone else makes to the original are not reflected here.

---

#### How to update `origin/master` from `upstream/master`

Suppose that you initially fork their repository and then clone your fork and add `upstream` to it, and all three are in sync.  You have this in your local Git repository:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
```

Now `upstream` make a new commit, which we'll call `D`.  You run `git fetch upstream` and pick it up:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        D   <-- upstream/master
```

You can now advance your `master` to point to `D`, and then `git push origin master`.  That will send `D` to `origin` and ask `origin` to make its `master` point to `D`.

But what if you're not ready to do that yet, for whatever reason?  Well, instead of `git push origin master`, you can run:

```
git push origin upstream/master:master
```

The name on the left of the colon `:` here is your `upstream/master`, which identifies commit `D`.  That's the commit you have that they—`origin`—need.  Your Git sends this commit to their Git, which adds it to their (`origin`'s) repository.  Then your Git asks their Git to set the name on the right of the colon: your Git asks them, `origin`, to set *their* `master` to point to commit `D`.

If and when this all works, your Git now has:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- upstream/master, origin/master
```

which represents the state of all three repositories: everyone has all four commits, *you* call the third one `master`, and they—`origin` and `upstream`—call the fourth one `master`.

When you're ready, you can move your `master` to point to commit `D` too.

It's up to *you* when to move each name around.  They're your names!  Even the remote-tracking names are yours, but it only makes sense to have your Git move them around based on the result of a `git fetch` or `git push` operation, because the whole point of these names is to remember what is in *their* repositories.

Again, the key here is that **it is the commits that are shared**.  The *names* are only useful for *finding* the commits.  In particular, a branch name finds the *last* commit that is part of that branch.  Branch names therefore move around over time.  Normally, they move so that they have *more* commits in them.  It's possible, with force, to yank a name "backwards", so that it becomes hard to find a later commit.  Some operations, such as `git commit --amend`, make a new commit and then yank a name sort of sideways, as it were:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

You might at this point decide that commit `I` is bad, and use `git commit --amend` to fix it up.  This does not—*can* not—actually change `I`.  The universally-agreed-on hash ID trick won't let that happen.  So your Git just makes a new and improved commit, which we can call `J` or maybe `I'` to indicate that it's the new and improved `I`.  Instead of making `I'` point back to `I`, your Git makes `I'` point back to `H`:

```
          I   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          I'  <-- master (HEAD)
```

Commit `I` does not actually go away—at least not for a while.<sup>2</sup>  But your name `master` has been yanked over sideways, as it were, to point to new-and-improved `I'` instead.  As long as you have never *sent* commit `I` anywhere or showed anyone its hash ID, nobody else can even know that you did this.  They have not seen it happen, you don't show them, and they never have to care.

If you *have* sent someone else commit `I`, though, they may have it find-able by some of *their* names.  This is when things get hard.  You can ask them, whoever they are, to throw out the bad commits.  If you control the repository, like your `origin` fork on GitHub, you can `git push --force` to throw out the bad commits.  Generally, though, this is a path to avoid: it's full of annoyance at least, and occasionally more serious pain.  In specific circumstances, when everyone has agreed to all of this in advance, the annoyance is mild, and it's OK.

Using `git rebase` leads to this same annoying situation: it's fine if you've all agreed to it in advance, or if no one else has seen these commits yet.  Otherwise, it's up to you to decide if the annoyance is worth doing new-and-improved commits.

Last, there are *pull requests*, which are a host-provider-specific thing.  These are not part of Git!  You do these by sending commits to your fork, and then using clicky web interface buttons to get GitHub to send those commits to the owners of the repository that you forked, asking them (humans) to incorporate these commits.  The commits you send in this process have to be in *your* fork, so you generally do this with a sequence: `git push origin ...` followed by using the web interface.

If and when the people who manage the GitHub repository you call `upstream` *take* your commits, your `git fetch upstream` will see your commits (with their original hash IDs) and update your `upstream/*` remote-tracking names.  Or, they might not take your commits as-is: they might make their own modified versions, with *different* hash IDs.  This is at least mildly annoying, like the whole amend or rebase situation: you may now have to abandon your original commits and rebuild any new work on their copies.

---

<sup>2</sup>Commits that cannot be reached by starting at some name and working backwards eventually get reaped by the Grim <s>Reaper</s> Collector, `git gc`.